Convert sqlalchemy orm model (PostgreSQL Ltree extansion) to pydantic
How could I correctly convert my sqlalchemy ORM model field [using PostgreSQL LTREE extension] to pydantic model or string [to use later in FastAPI]?

I have sqlalchemy and pydantic models:
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy_utils import LtreeType  # Postgres LTREE extension

from pydantic import BaseModel

# Sqlalchemy ORM <- Works as expected, fetches data
class ItemORM(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)  # 1
    label: Mapped[str]  # 'Some custom label'
    path: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(LtreeType) # 'A.23', THIS TO BE CONVERTED TO PYDANTIC OR STRING

# Pydantic
class Item(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(arbitrary_types_allowed=True) # Allows to use LtreeType type for pydantic

    id: int
    label: str
    path: LtreeType | str

My FastAPI code to fetch data and show it to user:
async get_data():
  with Session() as session:
    db_data = session.query(ItemORM).first() # '[(<ItemORM id='1',label='Label',path='A.21'>)]'
    item_dto: Item = Item.model_validate(db_data, from_attributes=True) # <- this generates error

When I try to execute it, it gives error:
item.path.is-instance[LtreeType]
  Input should be an instance of LtreeType [type=is_instance_of, input_value=Ltree('A.23'), input_type=Ltree]
  For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/is_instance_of

item.path.str
  Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=Ltree('A.23'), input_type=Ltree]
  For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.9/v/string_type

I've tried different pydantic types - str, None, LTreeType, tried to use validators, bus still success isn't mine, not able to convert specific database type into string.
How can I achieve that?
Thanks!

As a workaround I'm using manual pydantic validation with str() method:
item_dto: Item = Item.model_validate(
  {
    id': db_data.id,
    'label': db_data.label,
    'path': str(db_data.path),
  }
)


The code below is working for me. What I had to learn:

sqlalchemy_utils.LtreeType is to be used when declaring the mapped column
the custom type LtreeField needs to provide PlainValidator, PlainSerializer and WithJsonSchema

Code:
from re import sub
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    Field,
    PlainSerializer,
    PlainValidator,
    WithJsonSchema,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    DeclarativeBase,
    Mapped,
    mapped_column,
)
from sqlalchemy_utils import Ltree, LtreeType

LtreeField = Annotated[
    Ltree,
    PlainValidator(lambda v: Ltree(v)),
    PlainSerializer(lambda v: v.path),
    WithJsonSchema({"type": "string", "examples": ["some.path"]}),
]


def slugify(s):
    s = s.lower().strip()
    s = sub(r"[^\w\s-]", "", s)
    s = sub(r"[\s_-]+", "_", s)
    s = sub(r"^-+|-+$", "", s)
    return s


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class ItemORM(Base):
    __tablename__ = "item"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    label: Mapped[str]
    path: Mapped[Ltree] = mapped_column(LtreeType, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, parent_path: Ltree = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ltree_id = Ltree(slugify(self.label))
        self.path = ltree_id if parent_path is None else parent_path + ltree_id


class ItemIn(BaseModel):
    label: str
    parent_path: LtreeField | None = Field(default=None)


class ItemOut(BaseModel):
    label: str
    path: LtreeField


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/", response_model=ItemOut)
def create_item(*, item_in: ItemIn):
    print("item_in\t\t", f"{item_in!r}")
    item = ItemORM(**item_in.model_dump())
    print("item\t\t", f"{item!r}")
    print("item.path\t", f"{item.path!r}")
    return item

